# How to grab images from other page in background using only JS?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, image

I'm making a Chrome extension and am wanting to load a page in the background and grab images from it. I know that I could do this using jQuery's `$.get()` function followed by several `indexOf()` statements nested within a loop, something like:

```
  $.get("http://...",
    function(response) {
      a=response.indexOf("<IMG ", a)+1;

      while (a>0)
      {
        ...
```

but I'm wondering if there's an easier way, maybe loading the page in an invisible iframe with the background script and looping through all the IMG objects in it? I've never done that before so any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: This won't really work if images are placed with css (using background-image:url(..), f.i.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` is probably a jQuery object (assuming you're using jQuery), so you can treat it as one:

```
$.get("http://...",
    function(response) {
      $('img', response).each(function() {
        console.log('My src is: ' + $(this).prop('src'));
      }
```